# How can I make one table row the same height as the row of another table?

Tags: css

I have two tables. I made a fiddle so you can see it:

https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content" style="overflow-x:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>                
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
<tr> <td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td> Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr> <tr> <td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td> </td><td> Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>             
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
     <div id="sidebar">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
           <tbody>      
            <tr><th>Lorem ipsum<tr><th>Lorem ipsum  </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
<div id="cleared"></div>
```

I wish now that the rows on the right side will automatically get the size of the table on the left side. Is this possible?

Comment: why you have `<br>` tag

Comment: @Shehary Sorry, the <br> was of course a mistake, I will update my question

Comment: check my answer and see if it's what you are looking for

Comment: @Shehary Sorry, I was a little bit confused, I needed the <br> to show, that the content of my row is always changing in the height. I took your suggested code and made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/6/ But it is not the result I need, If my row has more lines of content the height of both tables don't match

Comment: yeah offcourse my solution will not work in that case, cause you having dynamic height in one table row and wana adjust the other table row according to it,

Comment: Yeah this is my problem, do you think I need javascript to achieve this?

Comment: yes, javascript or jQuery, i tried couple of ways but still didn't get it to work, best of luck.

Comment: Thank you anyways for your help :)

Comment: I updated the answer, check updated code with dynamic height solution

Comment: I tried your code in the fiddle, but it is still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/7/ Did I miss something?

Comment: you didn't add the jQuery library in your fiddle, here my working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8xomfoa0/

Comment: Oh right sorry :) Thank you! This works very well!!

Comment: you are most welcome and don't forget to mark the answer correct :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is with dynamic height, if one table row height increase, 2nd table respective row height will also increase with same height

Assign `ids` to both table and add following script

```js
$('#table1 tr').each(function(i,el) {
    var hgt = $(this).height();
    $('#table2 tr').eq(i).height(hgt);
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:40px;
}
table{
  font-size:13px;white-space: nowrap;
}
.container{
  padding:0px
}
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  margin-right: -420px;
}  
#wrapper {
  margin-right: 240px;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 240px;
  margin-right: -240px;
}  
#cleared {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content" style="overflow-x:scroll">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table1">
      <thead>
    <tr>
    
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>    
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
     <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   
    <tr> 
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum  <br> Lorem ipsum </td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
     
     <div id="sidebar">
           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table2">
            <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
             </tr>
            </thread>
       <tbody>      
    <tr>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                       
                  </tbody>
           </table>
     </div>
<div id="cleared"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I needed the <br> to show how it looks like if my row has more lines of content https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/6/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
height: 300px;
```

or whatever height you need

js:  https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/1/

the reason that row is taller is because of this:

```
<td>Lorem ipsum
    <br>Lorem ipsum<br>
</td>
```

you are adding line breaks. Plus they are two different tables. You can't expect them to behave exactly the same unless you do it in css. Or have the same 
 in the second table

Comment: well check your fiddle back..even in  your given fiddle height is not same..and you can't give fix height as its not what op asked..

Comment: Actually in my jsfiddle the table heights ARE the same. I'll check on another solution, but the heights are the same.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but in your fiddle the tables do not have the same height

Comment: hmm..weird..i just checked again and they are literall top to top and bottom to bottom. I'm using chrome on a mac....i dunno why everyone else doesn't see it the same. Oh well, I tried

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the height of the cells in both tables to the same value so that they will line up; however this obviously means that the cells won't always fit the contents.

Instead, you can link the tables into a single table, then set `visibility:hidden;` on some blank cells to provide the same effect. Still perhaps not what you want, but always an option:

```
tr th:nth-of-type(dummyColumn) {
    visibility:hidden;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(dummyColumn) {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Say you have one table with 3 columns and another with 1 column, you can merge them into a single table with a hidden column to create the same appearance. Below is an example, with the 4th column (an empty column) as the gap between the columns; the size of the gap can be adjusted by changing the width of the header and cells in the 4th column.

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SolveItSimply/o6frhmLx/4/

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you for your answer. But I do not understand, why would I make my table invisible?

Comment: You wouldn't hide the cells with data in them; you're just hiding a column of blank cells so that the columns to the left look separate from those on the right.

Comment: What I need is, if a row has in some cases more lines and becomes bigger, then my right table rows also need to match the new height: https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/6/

Comment: Do you need the tables to be separate entities? I realise my method is kind of 'hacky', but it will work for cells with different heights: https://jsfiddle.net/SolveItSimply/o6frhmLx/2/

Comment: Hi, thank you. You deleted an important part of my code. I added it into your last fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o6frhmLx/3/, the table on the right (id=sidebar) is the one whose rows should match the same height of the table rows of the left table (id=content)